# Terraform data "google_compute_global_address" returns null address

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

Load balancer already exists in the GCP project. I'm using data resource to get its IP but it is returning null.

Here it is the data resource

```
data "google_compute_global_address" "gateway" {
  name    = "XYZ"
  project = "abc"
}
```

Here is the output

```
output "gateway" {
  description = "LB IP"
  sensitive   = true
  value = {
    gateway_ip      = data.google_compute_global_address.gateway.address
  }
}
```

Here is the output result

[Click on this to see output result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29D2n.png)

Comment: Is this an external load balancer? Is it using a reserved static IP - https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address?

Comment: Yes, this is an external load balancer. This may not be using the reserved static IP. We are using Kubernetes Gateway API and we thought that it would reserve IP as well but seems like this is not the case. Thanks for pointing this out.